# Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled

Tags: micropython, tflm

I am running micropython code from this repo [tensorflow-micropython-examples](https://github.com/mocleiri/tensorflow-micropython-examples). I print the mem info before invoking the interpreter `interpreter.invoke()`

```
GC: total: 4098240, used: 2251528, free: 1846712
 No. of 1-blocks: 26462, 2-blocks: 99, max blk sz: 67725, max free sz: 115420
mem_info:  None
```

However I get the following error which makes no sense as I have sufficient memory and the interpreter was successfully loaded in

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (InstrFetchProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
```

Comment: this appears to be answered on GH: https://github.com/mocleiri/tensorflow-micropython-examples/issues/84,
so perhaps it should be removed here

Comment: @JosVerlinde That's my question

Comment: indeed, and there it has been identified as a likely code defect, so it makes sense to at least cross-ref them so save others needing to do this back-tracking